# Total workdays and hours query for personnel attendance table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables `Attendance_Employees` and `RFID_User`. Please help me to write this query.

`Attendance_Employees` table:

| Column Name | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| Name | varchar(100) |
| ID | varchar(50) |
| In_Date | date |
| In_Time | time(0) |
| In_Status | varchar(50) |
| Out_Date | date |
| Out_Time | time(0) |
| Out_Status | varchar(50) |

`RFID_User` table:

| Column Name | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| Name | varchar(100) |
| ID | varchar(50) |

I have two working SQL queries.

The SQL query I use to find the total days worked

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime
DECLARE @EndDate datetime
SET @StartDate = '2023-07-01'
SET @EndDate = '2023-07-31'

   SELECT [Name],[ID],  COUNT(*) as TotalWorkDays 
    FROM
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT [Name],[ID],CAST([In_Date] AS DATE) AS [Date]
      FROM [personnel_tracking].[dbo].[Attendance_Employees]
      WHERE [In_Date] IS NOT NULL
      AND CAST([In_Date] AS DATE) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
    )T
    GROUP BY [Name],[ID] Order by TotalWorkDays desc
```

Results :

| Name | ID | TotalWorkDays |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name | DASDF154 | 16 |
| name | 8E10FB57 | 16 |
| name | FE7AD957 | 15 |

The SQL query I use to find the daily working hours for a month

```
SELECT B.[Name],B.[ID],SUM(DailyWorkedHours) AS MonthlyWorkedHours
    FROM
        (
SELECT base.[Name],base.[ID],base.[Date],base.[In_Time],base.[Out_Time],SUM(base.HoursWorked) AS DailyWorkedHours
        FROM
        (
            SELECT [Name],[ID],[In_Time],[Out_Time],CAST(StartDateTime AS DATE) [Date],
                CASE
                    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) = 0 THEN
                        DATEDIFF(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) / 60.0
                    ELSE
                        DATEDIFF(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) / 60.0
                END HoursWorked
            FROM (
                SELECT [Name],[ID],[In_Date],[In_Time],[Out_Date],[Out_Time],CAST([In_Date] AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([In_Time] AS SMALLDATETIME) AS StartDateTime,
                    CASE
                        WHEN [In_Time] <= [Out_Time] THEN 
                            CAST([Out_Date] AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Out_Time] AS SMALLDATETIME)
                        ELSE
                            CAST([Out_Date] AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST([Out_Time] AS SMALLDATETIME)
                    END AS EndDateTime
                FROM
                [personnel_tracking].[dbo].[Attendance_Employees] WHERE [In_Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    ) AS firstDay
        ) AS base
        GROUP BY base.[Name],base.[ID],base.[In_Time],base.[Out_Time],base.[Date]  ) AS B  GROUP BY B.[Name],B.[ID] order by MonthlyWorkedHours desc
```

Results:

| Name | ID | MonthlyWorkedHours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name | DASDF154 | 169.549993 |
| name | 8E10FB57 | 156.066661 |

I want a combined version of the two queries. I want a result like this:

| Name | ID | TotalWorkDays | MonthlyWorkedHours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name | DASDF154 | 16 | 169.549993 |
| name | 8E10FB57 | 16 | 156.066661 |
| name | FE7AD957 | 15 | 146.349995 |

I updated the queries. I want the tables that I have obtained with the two queries to join. Can it be done with the " FULL OUTER JOIN " or "UNION" command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like you've drastically over engineered your solution here.
Without DDL/DML for your specific scenario it's hard to explicitly say.
Consider (inferring from your descriptions):

```
DECLARE @Attendance_Employees TABLE (Name VARCHAR(100), ID VARCHAR(50), In_Date DATE, In_Time TIME, In_Status VARCHAR(50), Out_Date DATE, Out_Time TIME, Out_Status VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @Attendance_Employees (Name, ID, In_Date, In_Time, In_Status, Out_Date, Out_Time, Out_Status) VALUES
('Bob', 1, '2023-07-01', '08:00', NULL, '2023-07-02', '02:00', NULL),
('Bob', 1, '2023-07-03', '08:00', NULL, '2023-07-03', '12:00', NULL),
('Joe', 2, '2023-07-01', '08:00', NULL, '2023-07-01', '12:00', NULL),
('Joe', 2, '2023-07-03', '08:00', NULL, '2023-07-03', '12:00', NULL);
```

With something similar to that, we can solve both questions with a single query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE;
SET @StartDate = '2023-07-01'
SET @EndDate = '2023-07-31'

SELECT Name, ID, COUNT(DISTINCT In_Date) AS DistinctStartDates, SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,In_Date, Out_Date)+1) AS TotalDays, SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CAST(In_Date AS DATETIME)+CAST(In_Time AS DATETIME),CAST(Out_Date AS DATETIME)+CAST(Out_Time AS DATETIME)))/60.0 AS TotalHours
  FROM @Attendance_Employees
 WHERE In_Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
 GROUP BY Name, ID;
```

| Name | ID | DistinctStartDates | TotalDays | TotalHours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 1 | 2 | 3 | 22.000000 |
| Joe | 2 | 2 | 2 | 8.000000 |

I wasn't sure if your intention was to only count the number of distinct start dates, or if you wanted the actual number of days worked. Bob worked from 8am on the first until 2am on the second. If this counts as two days, then `TotalDays` gives the answer, if it only counts as one then `DistinctStartDates` gives the answer.

Comment: Example:
Name| identity | Incoming_Date | on time | Exit_Date | End_Duration|
________________________________________________________
Bob | 1 | 2023-08-17 | 08:23 | 2023-08-17| 11:30|
Bob | 1 | 2023-08-17| 14:00 | 2023-18-17 | 18:00|

I want it to count as a single day if two logins are made in the same day.
Can you change your TotalDays to RealWorkDays?
Name| identity | DistinctiveStartDates| RealWorkDays|
_______________________________________
Bob | 1 | 16 | 15 |

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT In_Date)` will only count each distinct date once.

Answer (score 0):

What you likely want is something like the following where you literally plug your existing queries between the brackets where I have written `firstquery` and `secondquery`:

```
SELECT a.*, b.MonthlyWorkedHours
FROM (firstquery) a INNER JOIN (secondquery) b
  ON a.name = b.name AND a.ID = b.ID
```

I joined on `name` and `ID` since those are both in your `group by`. That won't hurt, but I assume your tables are set up so there will never be more than one `name` per `ID`, so joining on `ID` would probably be sufficient.

You mentioned using a `union`. A union could combine the information you want, but as separate rows. It wouldn't be possible to get the exact output format you want.

You mentioned using a `full outer join`. You would use that if there were a case where one of the queries had a record that didn't match one in the other query. e.g. Where a person has hours worked but no days, or has days worked but no hours. In your case, that doesn't sound like a scenario that needs to be considered, so the `inner join` is probably simpler. If you really want, though:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.name, b.name) name, COALESCE(a.ID, b.ID) ID, a.TotalWorkDays, b.MonthlyWorkedHours
FROM (firstquery) a FULL OUTER JOIN (secondquery) b
  ON a.name = b.name AND a.ID = b.ID
```

As an aside, your second query appears at first glance to be overly complicated. (Possibly I'm wrong and just being thrown off by all of the casting). With some sample data it might be possible for someone to help you write that in a more clear way.

Comment: You actually answered my question perfectly. I accepted the other answer as the other answer simplifies my query.